# Graph API - ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the ClosedChannelException error while sending a mail using Graph API.
I know the connection parameters are correct as it works fine when I tried via postman.
Also my old code with graph API 1.6.0 is working fine. I am trying to upgrade it to 5.45.0.
Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? Code looks correct to me. So I tried changing the dependent jar versions too but so far nothing worked.

I used the following code with TokenCredentialAuthProvider.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/v1.0/includes/snippets/java/user-sendmail-with-attachment-java-snippets.md

Versions used:
microsoft-graph - 5.45.0
azure-identity - 1.7.3
reactor-core - 3.5.2
reactor-netty - 1.1.2
netty-all - 4.1.87.Final

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error executing the request
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:410)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:225)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:202)
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:335)
        at com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserSendMailRequest.post(UserSendMailRequest.java:54)
        at com.test.GraphProducer.sendEmail(GraphProducer.java:151)
       .....................
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        .....................
        at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:407)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
       .....................
        at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:55)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:53)
        .....................
Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:408)
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
        at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.sendSync(HttpClient.java:42)
        .....................
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequestWithRetries(HttpHelper.java:96)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:49)
        ... 16 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                ... 34 more
        Suppressed: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:408)
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
                at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.sendSync(HttpClient.java:42)
                .....................
                ... 25 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                        ... 31 more
        Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
                .....................
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:408)
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
                at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.sendSync(HttpClient.java:42)
                .....................
                ... 26 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                        ... 32 more
        Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
                .....................
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:408)
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
                at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.sendSync(HttpClient.java:42)
                .....................
                ... 27 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                        ... 33 more
        Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(AbstractChannel.java:976)
                .....................
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(AbstractChannel.java:976)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:237)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:533)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:517)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:457)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:942)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:217)
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doConnect$8(TransportConnector.java:240)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Update on '03Feb2022':
I tried the below code to check if token part is working and found out that it is throwing the same error.

```
IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");  
            String token = authProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync(url).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a version conflict issue. Used netty-all - 4.1.80.Final version in maven to fix it.